# How to move a specific person to a specific VC

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get it so when you type a command it will move me instantly, right now you have to @me on discord

```
@commands.command(name='movejohan', aliases=['mj', 'MJ'])
async def MoveJ(self, message, member: discord.Member = None):
    """Moves Johan to xxxxx"""
    channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxxxxx)
    await member.move_to(channel, reason='Moved By {}'.format(message.author))
```

This is what I have and I don't know how to make it so it moves me specifically, I thought to change `member: discord.Member = None` to `member: discord.Member = bot.get_user(xxxxxxxx)`
but that did not work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you're using the `member: discord.Member = None` argument.

I'd suggest something like this:

```py
@commands.command(name='movejohan', aliases=['mj', 'MJ'])
async def MoveJ(self, message, member: discord.Member = None):
    """Moves Johan to xxxxx"""
    if not member:
        member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=xxxxxxxx) # put your user ID here!
        # As Fin mentioned, you can also use message.guild.get_member(userID)
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(xxxxxxxxxx)
    await member.move_to(channel, reason='Moved By {}'.format(message.author))
```

When you're putting in the member argument, you can use any attribute a member has - you can use their user ID, display name, username, you don't need to explicitly mention them.

Answer (score 2):

You want to specify the guild to get the member from, which can be done using context:

```
@commands.command(name='movejohan', aliases=['mj', 'MJ'])
async def MoveJ(self, message):
    """Moves Johan to xxxxx"""
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(xxxxx)
    johan = message.guild.get_member(xxxxx)
    await johan.move_to(channel, reason='Moved by {}'.format(message.author))
```